# Django views error when deployed

Tags: django, django-deployment

I have modified the following method on my development machine and it works perfectly fine there:

```
def profile_search(request):
    args = {}
    qs=[]
    if request.method == 'GET':        
        page = request.GET.get('page')
        print 'page is:' + str(page)
        if 'search-profiles-post' in request.session: 
            request.POST = QueryDict('').copy()
            request.POST.update(request.session['search-profiles-post'])            
            request.method = 'POST' 


    if request.method == "POST":
        form = AdvancedSearchForm(request.POST)
        request.session['search-profiles-post'] = request.POST


        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data

            s_country=cd['country']
            s_province=cd['province']
            s_city = cd['city']

            if s_country: qs.append(Q(country__icontains = s_country))
            if s_province: qs.append( Q(province__icontains=s_province))             
            if s_city: qs.append( Q(city__icontains=s_city))




            f = None
            for q in qs:
                if f is None: 
                    f=q                                  
                else: f &=q
            print f

            if f is not None:
                profiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(f).order_by('-created_at') 


        else:
            form = AdvancedSearchForm()
            profiles = UserProfile.objects.all().order_by('-created_at') 

    paginator = Paginator(profiles,12) # << This line is problematic

    page= request.GET.get('page')
    try:
        results = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        results = paginator.page(1)  

    except EmptyPage:
            results = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)        

    args.update(csrf(request))    
    args['form'] = form  
    args['results'] = results
    return render_to_response('userprofile/advanced_search.html', args,
                              context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

However when I copy the views into my production (which worked fine before the modification) I get this error:

```
UnboundLocalError at /search/
local variable 'profiles' referenced before assignment
```

Traceback:

```
File "/root/.djenv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "./userprofile/views.py" in profile_search
  739.     paginator = Paginator(profiles,12)

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /search/
Exception Value: local variable 'profiles' referenced before assignment
```

As far as I can say, the only code that is different between my production and development is the settings.py (which use different databases).

Since the search queries are to be saved into session, I suspect it has something to do with session handing in production but I don't know how.

A point that might be relevant: While I have installed debug-toolbar on my production machine, I can not see its tab even at debug mode.

I appreciate your hints to fix this.

Comment: there is a execution path where profiles variable is not defined. form is valid and f is None.

Comment: @eugene not sure how this is relevant to different behavior between dev and production.

Comment: for example your `qs` is empty in prod not in dev.

Comment: @eugene so what do you suggest to avoid the problem?

Comment: well, I just pointed out the one of the reasons of your problem. how to solve it is.. well you should be prepared to handle all execution path?

Comment: @eugene will you please elaborate your answer in a modifed views. I'll try it and accept your answer it eliminates the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the `profiles` variable not being defined in production.

There is a code path that doesn't define your `profiles` variable.

Upon closer look, you should be able to why it's happening.

your `qs` may be empty, your assumption that `request.method` must be either `get or post` might be wrong. (client might send patch, delete request). There could be more reasons...

In any case, your code has holes that doesn't define `profiles` variable, and your production server (or client using the server) is different in a sense that it is going through the different execution path.

You could put a `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` and debug it.
or mentally analyse your code to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Put or copy the

paginator = Paginator(profiles,12)

under

profiles = UserProfile.objects.filter(f).order_by('-created_at')

with the same indentation. I think the value of f is not None, and based-on dislayed code, your pagination is outside of the profile_search(), so i think the assignment of profilles failed.